# XPath con multiples resultados

Tags: xml, xpath

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo con un fichero xml:

```
<Animals>
<Animal id="1" ranking="1">
<Name>Lion</Name>
<Sex>Male</Sex>
<Year_2022>
<TotalFood>20</TotalFood>
<FoodEaten>12</FoodEaten>
<FoodLost>8</FoodLost>
</Year_2022>
```

Quiero sacar una sentencia XPath el cual para el año 2022 me de el animal que mas FoodEaten ha comido de ese año con un texto que diga, El animal X ha comido un total de Y en el año 2022.

Tambien si hay dos resultados que sean lo mismo, coja el primero de este:

He probado:

```
max(doc("AnimalWorld.xml")//Animals/Animal[contains(Sex,"Male")]/Year_2022[FoodEaten=max(doc(""AnimalWorld.xml"")//Animals/Animal/Year_2020/FoodEaten)]/following::Year_2022[position()=1]/../Year_2022/FoodEaten/text())
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado ya que me muestra el maximo del animal que ha comido en 2022 pero no hay forma de que me muestre tambien el nombre del animal que en este caso seria Lion.

Es decir, como añado dos resultados a un mismo XPath

¿alguna idea?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La versión actual de XPath es 3.1, utilizando esa versión puedes escribir

```
let $max := max(//Animal/Year_2022/FoodEaten),
    $primer-animal-con-max := //Animal[Year_2022/FoodEaten = $max] => head()
return 'El animal ' || $primer-animal-con-max/Name || ' ha comido un total de ' || $max || ' en el año 2022'
```

[Ejemplo en línea](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=let%20%24max%20%3A%3D%20max%28%2F%2FAnimal%2FYear_2022%2FFoodEaten%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%24primer-animal-con-max%20%3A%3D%20%2F%2FAnimal%5BYear_2022%2FFoodEaten%20%3D%20%24max%5D%20%3D%3E%20head%28%29%0Areturn%20%27El%20animal%20%27%20%7C%7C%20%24primer-animal-con-max%2FName%20%7C%7C%20%27%20ha%20comido%20un%20total%20de%20%27%20%7C%7C%20%24max%20%7C%7C%20%27%20en%20el%20a%C3%B1o%202022%27&input=%3CAnimals%3E%0D%0A%3CAnimal%20id%3D%221%22%20ranking%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%3CName%3ELion%3C%2FName%3E%0D%0A%3CSex%3EMale%3C%2FSex%3E%0D%0A%3CYear_2022%3E%0D%0A%3CTotalFood%3E20%3C%2FTotalFood%3E%0D%0A%3CFoodEaten%3E12%3C%2FFoodEaten%3E%0D%0A%3CFoodLost%3E8%3C%2FFoodLost%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FYear_2022%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FAnimal%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FAnimals%3E&input-type=XML), utilizado [SaxonJS 2.5](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) para evaluar XPath 3.1, da el resultado

```
El animal Lion ha comido un total de 12 en el año 2022
```

para tu ejemplo de datos.